# Group data by day

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by

I have a table **transaction** with data as below:

```
date       | status  | delivered | products
-------------------------------------------
03.10.2014 | SUCCESS |      TRUE | 4
03.10.2014 | FAILURE |      FAIL | 0
03.10.2014 | SUCCESS |      FAIL | 1
03.10.2014 | SUCCESS |      FAIL | 4
04.10.2014 | SUCCESS |      TRUE | 24
04.10.2014 | SUCCESS |      TRUE | 5
04.10.2014 | FAILURE |      FAIL | 0
```

Now I want to group data by day, it's look like:

```
date       | success_status | failure_status | delivered | total_products
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
03.10.2014 | 3              | 1              | 1         | 9
04.10.2014 | 2              | 1              | 2         | 29
```

I know how to **sum(products) as total_products**, **group by date**.

But how can I get the remaining columns **success_status, failure_status** and **delivered** in a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a conditional sum:

```
select date, 
       sum(case when status = 'SUCCESS' and delivered then products end) as success_status,
       sum(case when status = 'FAILURE' then products end) as failure_status,
       sum(case when delivered then products end) as delivered,
       sum(products) as total_products
from the_table
group by date
```

in the upcoming 9.4 version you will be able to write this a bit more elegantly (and it might make it clearer on what the `case` is doing)

```
SELECT date, 
       sum(products) filter (status = 'SUCCESS' and delivered) as large_orders_amount,
       sum(products) filter (status = 'FAILURE') as failure_status,
       sum(products) filter (delivered) as delivered,
       sum(products) as total_products
from the_table
group by date
```

---

Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's also a reserved word, but more importantly it doesn't document what the column contains. The delivery date, the receive date, the cancel date, ...?

Comment: Thank you very much!
Just modify a little bit. success_status, failure_status and delivered need to use count(...)